# Calculating the number of terms in arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that if I have a set of numbers, let's say+

$1,2,3,4,5$ 
I can find the number of terms by subtraction the last term $5$ from the first terms $1$ and then add $1$: $(5-1)+1 = 5$, then the number of terms = 5.This is pretty much easy example just to make my question clearer.

*In arithmetic sequence I wanted to (know the number of terms) using these details:

$s_n = 270$

$d = 1$

$a_1 = 4$

I thought about it and used the formula: $s_n = {n\over 2}(2a(n-1)d)$
then I substitute

$270 = {n\over 2} (2(4)+(n-1)(1))$

$270 = {n\over 2}(8+n-1)$

$270 = {7n+n^2\over 2}$

$540 = 7n+n^2$ # I dont think this works ?

Comment: It does! Tried solving it? And pick the positive value for n you obtain!

Comment: Typo: you're missing the $+$ in $(2a+(n−1)d)$

Comment: Solving the quadratic equation: $n^2+7n-540 = (n-20)(n+27)$ then the solution cannot be -20 so 27 ?

Comment: See the answer; and what are the solutions of $(n−20)(n+27)=0$? -20,27 or 20,-27?

Comment: I got the same answer as you did, but I never really thought about solving the quadratic equation for the sake of knowing the number of terms, this was completely out of my thinking ! which is 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the quadratic equation; and choose the positive value for n you obtain as solution.

---

**Edit:**

> $(n-20)(n+27)=0\implies n-20=0 \text{ or } n+27=0\implies n=20\text{ or }-27$, now pick the positive one of it.

Comment: Could you give me more exercises ?

Comment: For quadratic equations or ones like you have asked? Try your luck with google. I found few problems with arithmetic sequences here: http://www.math10.com/en/algebra/arithmetic-progression.html Hope it helps!

Comment: I appreciate that. Thank you.